# "Invalid scalar projection" error after doing a JOIN and then FILTER in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am using [Pig 0.12.1](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html). Why am I getting an error when I `FILTER` after doing a `JOIN` by `LEFT OUTER`?

Here is a modified example:

```
A = LOAD '$file1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (idA:int, manufacturer:chararray);
B = LOAD '$file2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (idB:int, price:float);
C = JOIN A BY idA LEFT OUTER, B BY idB;
D = FILTER C BY price > 2.0;
```

Why do I get this "Invalid scalar projection" error on `D`:

```
ERROR pig.PigServer: exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse:
Invalid scalar projection: D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,
You can access the price column by,

```
D = FILTER C BY $3 > 2.0;
or
D = FILTER C BY B::price > 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accounting for any `NULL`s in the relation.

```
D = FILTER C BY price > 2.0 AND price is not null;
```